# Is it possible to download an excel file off from MS TEAMs using a script from VB.NET and edit it?

Tags: vb.net, microsoft-teams

I am just wondering if this is even possible. I haven't even started doing this or anything, but just wanted to see what have others have done (any tips or so) if they have tried it.

Comment: Doesn't Teams just let you edit the file right within Teams? Just curious as to why do it within a separate app.

Comment: Yeah that's true, but i would really like to incorporate a few things from VB.Net

Comment: Perhaps this is a starting point? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tutorials/get-started-dotnet-app-studio

Comment: All the files in Teams are saved in Sharepoint. All those files can be downloaded using [SharePoint api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest). The second option can be the Teams graph api.